# Getting Client IP Address

Tags: php, android, networking, ip

I am trying to get the ip address of the client using a url from php and from the same device using his installed android app, but in both the scenario i am getting 2 different ip address. Can anyone explain the reason, why?

PHP Code --

```
function getRealIpAddr()
    {
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        else
        {
          $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
```

Android Code --

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
        try {
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress.hashCode());
                        Log.i("IP Address", ip);
                        return ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            Log.e("Error IP", ex.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: in android, if using WIFI, it will give you the local network IP. You basically can never expect that you can get client real IP address on the client side.

Comment: In my scenario, i am using the mobile internet, and clicked both the links from my mobile only, so it should display the same ip address both from php code and android code. But its showing 2 different ip address from both the codes.

Comment: as I said, your mobile ISP may not give you your real IP address, but use a proxy, or whatever else. Never expect it to be real.

Answer (score 0):

You will get different results if you are behind NAT and your PHP server is outside of your network. Your PHP code will give back your external/public IP address and your Android code will give back your private IP address used by your phone on LAN, behind your NAT router.